# Pythonic way to replace values in a list according to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, replace

I need to convert a list values according to values contained into a Python dictionary.

I have a list as the following:

```
lst = ["hello", "word", "bye", "my", "friend", "hello"]
```

And a dictionary obtained using a cluster procedure, so the keys are the labels and the values the categories:

```
my_dict = {0: ["hello", "word"], 1: ["my", "friend"], 2: ["bye"]}
```

I need to faster convert the original list into:

```
new_lst = [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Consider that in the real case the list length is near 60k and so I need an efficient way to do this operation.

Comment: Is using pandas ok?

Comment: no, it's not in Pandas and I prefer not to load the list into Pandas if possible

Comment: Got it! Especially for large lists, using pandas might be substantially faster. So if you want, I could post a pandas solution as a small extra. :)

Comment: yes, absolutely! I prefer not to use pandas since I am working in a quite big project that currently is not developed in Pandas. Anyway, if it possible to save a lot of time, I can consider to switch to Pandas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = ["hello", "word", "bye", "my", "friend", "hello"]
my_dict = {0: ["hello", "word"], 1: ["my", "friend"], 2: ["bye"]}

inverse_dict = {b:a for a,c in my_dict.items() for b in c}

new_lst = [inverse_dict.get(a) for a in lst]
```

Comment: I accept the answer since it got the point. Just to sharing, I add an ```if``` condition in order to check if the token ```a``` is into ```inverse_dict```: ```[inverse_dict[a] if a in inverse_dict.keys() else np.nan for a in lst]```

Comment: @AndreaM you can use .get to avoid the if condition. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in doing this in `pandas`:

```
my_dict = {0: ["hello", "word"], 1: ["my", "friend"], 2: ["bye"]}
# revert the dict
my_dict_rev = {k2: k for k, v in my_dict.items() for k2 in v}
# convert the list to a pandas Series
ser = pd.Series(["hello", "word", "bye", "my", "friend", "hello"])
# replace the values
rev_ser = ser.replace(my_dict_rev)
```

I know that the answer is not asking for a `pandas` solution, but especially for **large** lists, `pandas` will probably be substantially faster. Also perhaps someone else already using `pandas` will see this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do this with simple list-comprehension also. No need to use Pandas .

```
lst = ["hello", "word", "bye", "my", "friend", "hello"]
my_dict = {0: ["hello", "word"], 1: ["my", "friend"], 2: ["bye"]}

result = []
[result.append(k) for word in lst for k,v in my_dict.items() if word in v]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: This is not a correct list comprehension. Look at @warped 's answer to see the implementation of a correct list comprehension.